# Fancy box opening image in new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox, fancybox-2

I had Fancybox working perfectly to open images in the same window but now they are opening in a new page.

I've figured out the problem; I've added a piece of jQuery that seems to have stopped Fancybox working properly. I just don't know enough about jQuery to know why this is happening or how to fix it.

This is the script that stops Fancybox working. When I delete it Fancybox works again, but I want this script to make an image scroller on my page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var scroller = $('#scroller div.innerScrollArea');
        var scrollerContent = scroller.children('ul');
        scrollerContent.children().clone().appendTo(scrollerContent);
        var curX = 0;
        scrollerContent.children().each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.css('left', curX);
            curX += $this.outerWidth(true);
        });
        var fullW = curX / 2;
        var viewportW = scroller.width();

        // Scrolling speed management
        var controller = {curSpeed:0, fullSpeed:0};
        var $controller = $(controller);
        var tweenToNewSpeed = function(newSpeed, duration)
        {
            if (duration === undefined)
             duration = 1;
            $controller.stop(true).animate({curSpeed:newSpeed}, duration);
        };

        // Pause on hover
        scroller.hover(function(){
            tweenToNewSpeed(1);
        }, function(){
            tweenToNewSpeed(controller.fullSpeed);
        });

        // Scrolling management; start the automatical scrolling
        var doScroll = function()
        {
            var curX = scroller.scrollLeft();
            var newX = curX + controller.curSpeed;
            if (newX > fullW*2 - viewportW)
                newX -= fullW;
            scroller.scrollLeft(newX);
        };
        setInterval(doScroll, 20);
        tweenToNewSpeed(controller.fullSpeed);
    });
</script>
```

My website's here: [Snakes & Ladders page.](http://www.jameslester.xyz/portfolio/snakesandladders/snakesandladders.html) The issues the same on all of the portfolio pages.

Comment: Maybe the very first line of your code above because jQuery might be already loaded (you don't need to load it again) ... try removing that line first to see what happens. Also make sure the rest of your code is also loaded AFTER jQuery

Comment: Brilliant, works great now. Thanks, I really appreciate it :)

Comment: Can you write about the solution in the answer box provided? This is preferable to editing the word "solved" into the question.